# Astro in Docker not refresh

Tags: docker, dockerfile, astrojs

I am creating an Astro js container with Docker on windows.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.15
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 24678
CMD ["npm","run","dev","--","--host"]
```

I build my image with the following command

```
docker build . -t astro
```

I run my container with this command

```
docker run --name astro1 -p 24678:24678 -v D:\Workspace\Docker\Practicas\docker-astro-example:/app -v /app/node_modules/ astro
```

So far without problems but when I make a change in the index.astro document it does not refresh the page to see the changes.

Comment: Are you making changes inside the container or on your host machine?

Comment: How do you run *.astro files? If it need a kind of build, the simple edition it is not enough

Comment: on both sides and does not refresh the screen

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can config Vite in the Astro's astro.config.mjs file to enable hot reloading in a docker container.

```js
export default defineConfig({
    vite: {
        server: {
            watch: { usePolling: true }
        },
    },
});
```

You have more details in this issue.

https://github.com/withastro/docs/issues/4003#issuecomment-1660342571